# Macro to prevent code processing

Tags: c++, debugging, comments

So I've a piece of code, which will access a DLL namespace function if it's in Debug mode, and  which I'd like to comment out if it's in Release.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
       #define (DEBUG_CODE)  abcd::
#else
       #define   (DEBUG_CODE)  <Condition to skip processing>


       if (some condition)
              (DEBUG_CODE) func_name();
```

While I'd like the `#else` to define a comment, I suppose you can't do that because they're skipped by the compiler before any code processing, or preprocessing is performed..

If that is correct, then kindly tell me a way to skip the processing of `(DEBUG_CODE) func_name();`. There are a lot of places where it is used, and I don't wish to add `if(DEBUG)` everywhere.

**EDIT**

The namespace DLL has functions which do not return anything, as well as functions which are expected to return a value, and which might be assigned to an `enum`.

i.e.

```
 abcd::func_name();
and
  int rs = abcd::func_name_2();
and
  enum  XYZ{ var1 = 0; var2};
  XYZ PQR  = abcd::func_name3();  //This Enum will prevent me from defining some kind
                                  // 0; as a `#define`
```

So..multiple scenarios..

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this if you change `DEBUG_CODE` to

```
    #ifdef DEBUG
    #  define DEBUG_CODE(code) abcd::code;
    #else
    #  define DEBUG_CODE(code) ;
    #endif
```

and then you would call it like this:

```
    if(some_condition) DEBUG_CODE(func_name())
```

In debug mode this calls your function and in release mode no code is generated.

If you want to be able to assign the return values of these functions to variable or return from them (though I don't think it's a good idea, as I explain in the comments) I would make the macro take what to call in debug mode and what to use in release mode.

```
    #ifdef DEBUG
    #  define IF_DEBUG_ELSE(debug_code, release_code) abcd::debug_code
    #else
    #  define IF_DEBUG_ELSE(debug_code, release_code) release_code
    #endif
```

This makes it clear at least when you call the macro what's happening.
This can be used like:

```
    return IF_DEBUG_ELSE(check_result(), 0);//0 for success
    if(IF_DEBUG_ELSE(check_condition(), true)){}
    XYZ xyz = IF_DEBUG_ELSE(get_xyz(), First_XYZ);
```

and so on like that.

Comment: That might have worked well, except in certain cases, the `func_name()` is used as an expression to return a value to be assigned. e.g. `int rs = abcd::code`. If it is replaced by the `#define`, then it will amount to int rs = ;. I could do `#  define DEBUG_CODE(code) 0;`, but `rs` can be an Enum as well. I'll edit the question to reflect the different scenarios.

Comment: @user1173240 That seems like a bad idea, the debug code is supposed to be for extra checks to help development.  If you start returning these error values and start relying on them during development (or someone else does without realizing they are only debug checks) code will not work as expected.

Comment: @GuyGear I know, but this is an old part of code, which is being simplified. It longer needs the `abcd` DLL for ``release version, but we need it for debugging, else development will take a hit. I'm trying to cope as best with some sloppy design. The `if(DEBUG)` is inevitable anyway, I just want a cleaner way of doing it.

Comment: @user1173240 well, hopefully my edit will be sufficient then, it's hard to imagine doing better than that.

Comment: @GuyGear Thank you. Let me try it out.

Comment: @GuyGear Should suffice very well. Thanks a lot.